# Jenkinsfile and accepting merge requests

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a Jenkinsfile to test my ansible roles with Jenkins.

Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
    properties properties: [[$class: 'GitLabConnectionProperty', gitLabConnection: 'gitlab-connection-name']]

    node {
    ...
    stage ('Accept merge request') {    
        echo 'Accepting MR'
        acceptGitLabMR mergeCommitMessage: 'accepted'
        }
    }
```

The test passes without fail but changes are not merged on gitlab.

What's wrong?

Comment: so you're seeing "Accepting MR" in the output and you're positive it's running the acceptGitLabMR line it sounds like. what's the output when that command fails?

Comment: I use try-catch so if something fails then the stage 'Accept merge request' is not executed.